# UWP MediaPlayer replays music unexpectedly

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I am so sorry that I want you guys to debug for me but I really have no idea what's going wrong...

So this is the code that doesn't work as expected:

```
    public static async Task SetPlaylist(ICollection<Music> playlist, Music music = null)
    {
        int index = 0;
        if (CurrentPlaylist.Count > 0)
        {
            if (music == null)
            {
                CurrentPlaylist.Clear();
                PlayBackList.Items.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(music.Name);
                foreach (var item in CurrentPlaylist.ToArray())
                {
                    if (item.Equals(music)) index = 1;
                    else RemoveMusic(item);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(new string('=', 20));
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in playlist.Skip(index))
            await AddMusic(item);
        if (!CurrentPlaylist.Contains(CurrentMusic))
            CurrentMusic = null;
    }
```

What this function does is that, it resets the playlist, and if music is specified, do not remove that music from the playlist. This function is helpful when you set your music player to the shuffle mode while you are still playing the music. It will only shuffle the rest of the playlist without interrupting the current.

The problem is that, if I set a breakpoint on the first `foreach` and run through the `foreach` step by step, then it runs perfectly without any errors. However, if I press continue when it is still in the first `foreach`, then the current playing music will stop and restart, meaning that the current playing music might be removed and re-added to the playlist.

I have no idea how to debug it. I can only guess it might have something to do with the `async`. It is also giving the correct output even it doesn't behave as expected.

My source code is here: https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/MediaHelper.cs.

Comment: So your problem is that if you set shuffle mode the player will be interrupted, Right ?

Comment: Yes.@NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I check method, when you set `shuffle` mode, the `PlayBackList.Items.Clear();` will be clear.

Comment: Really? I never get to that part @NicoZhu-MSFT And I don't have that in the `foreach`.

Comment: Please check this `ShuffleAndPlay` method.

Comment: I have a little confuse with the logic of the play model, I think you need keep current playing music at any time.

Comment: I have that as the public variable of `MediaHelper`. And clicking the shuffle button should not be related to `ShuffleAndPlay ` but `ShuffleOthers`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199420/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-seaky-luo).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Hello, are you able to solve that?

Comment: I am checking your code.

Comment: I check your new demo, I found you have solved this issue, right?

Comment: Ha, I haven't contributed to my project for a while. I guess it cures itself.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It is back again :) I didn't change any part of that.

Comment: So, the issue still exist？

Comment: It exists currently. @NicoZhu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, and the problem was found in the `SetPlaylist(ICollection<Music> playlist, Music music = null)` method, which may be caused by frequent **remove** and **add** operations, and a conflict occurred. So I tried to test by updating the elements in the array and found that it worked, so you can try it with the code below.

```
public static async Task SetPlaylist(ICollection<Music> playlist, Music music = null)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in playlist.Skip(1))
    {
        index++;
        await FayAddMusic(item, index);
    }

    if (!CurrentPlaylist.Contains(CurrentMusic))
        CurrentMusic = null;

}

public static async Task FayAddMusic(Music music, int index)
{
    try
     {
         var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(music.Path);
         var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
         music.IsPlaying = false;
         source.CustomProperties.Add("Source", music);
         var item = new MediaPlaybackItem(source);

         // update element
         PlayBackList.Items[index] = item;
         CurrentPlaylist[index] = music;
      }
      catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
      {


      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had a chance to try it as today is still holiday for me, but how can you not remove it if you want a new playlist to be played?

Comment: It didn't mean I didn't delete it, I just turned the steps of (removing and adding) into updating. It means updating each item in the CurrentPlaylist or PlayBackList into the one corresponding to the new list, like `PlayBackList.Items[index] = item;`

Comment: If you simply update it, I think the current playing item will change while it is still playing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Faywang - MSFT, I have learned the reason why it replays. Although his provided solution doesn't seem to be good for me, I am very grateful for his help so I accepted his answer.

Here I just want to give out my solution.

First I created another `MediaPlaybackList` (I call it `PendingPlaybackList`) to put the new shuffled playlist. And I assigned it the value of `null`.

Then instead of putting everything in `SetPlaylist`, I started a new function called `ShuffleOthers` to do what I want:

```
    public static async Task SetPlaylist(ICollection<Music> playlist)
    {
        if (CurrentPlaylist.Count > 0) Clear();
        foreach (var item in playlist)
            await AddMusic(item);
        if (!CurrentPlaylist.Contains(CurrentMusic))
            CurrentMusic = null;
    }

    public static async void ShuffleOthers()
    {
        PendingPlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
        var playlist = ShufflePlaylist(CurrentPlaylist, CurrentMusic);
        CurrentPlaylist.Clear();
        foreach (var item in playlist)
            await AddMusic(item);
        CurrentPlaylist[0].IsPlaying = true;
    }
```

When `ShuffleOthers` is called, initialize `PendingPlaybackList`. And when `PlaybackList` needs to be accessed, which is usually the time when the current playing music needs changing, put everything from `PendingPlaybackList` to `_PlaybackList`. `_PlaybackList` is the source of `MediaPlayer`

```
    public static MediaPlaybackList PlaybackList
    {
        get
        {
            if (PendingPlaybackList != null)
            {
                if (PendingPlaybackList.Items.Count < _PlaybackList.Items.Count)
                    return PendingPlaybackList;
                _PlaybackList.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var item in PendingPlaybackList.Items)
                    _PlaybackList.Items.Add(item);
                PendingPlaybackList = null;
                _PlaybackList.MoveTo(0);
            }
            return _PlaybackList;
        }
    }
```

If my answer is confusing, my source code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/MediaHelper.cs). You are welcome to leave any comments.